# JUnit 5 Eclipse Java Testing

Tags: java, eclipse, junit5

I am doing JUnit5 testing using Mockito and here is the full code please have a look and let me know how to fix this :

```
package hotel.entities;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable;

import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Spy;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import hotel.credit.CreditCard;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyInt;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

class RoomTest {

    @Mock Booking booking;
    @Spy ArrayList <Booking> bookings;

    int roomID = 1;
    int stayLength = 1;
    RoomType roomtype = RoomType.SINGLE; 

    @InjectMocks Room room = new Room(roomID, roomtype);



    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception {
        room = new Room(roomID,roomtype);
        //booking = new Booking(guest, room,bookedArrival,stayLength,numberOfOccupants,creditCard);
        //booking = new checkout(booking);
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    void roomCheckin() {
        room.checkin();
        assertTrue(room.isAvailable(null, stayLength));
        Executable e = () -> room.checkin();
        Throwable t = assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, e);
    }

    @Test
    void roomCheckout() {

        bookings.add(booking);
        room.checkin();
        assertEquals(roomID , bookings.size());
        assertTrue(room.isAvailable(null, stayLength));
        room.checkout(booking);

        verify(bookings).remove(booking);
        assertTrue(room.isReady());
        assertEquals(0,bookings.size());
    }

}
```

I am getting error on this line while I am doing testing:
            bookings.add(booking);

please tell me how can I fix this null pointer exception from the code so that it runs properly and my tests get successful.

Here is the complete error trace please guide me how to fix this issue:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hotel.entities.RoomTest.roomCheckout(RoomTest.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:436)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:170)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:166)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:113)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

Comment: An error ? Which error ?

Comment: By the way you assertion is not very helpful

Comment: I am not able to define as I am very new in this,

Comment: Is it possible that you provide me line of code which pass my tests for the above 2 methods ?

Comment: but first what is your error ?

Comment: ... and second, what do you want to test? Please explain the purpose of the tests and its setup...

Comment: how can I see what is error ? Actually I think it is not error it is just my test method is getting failed

Comment: I just want to do unit testing and check if my implementation is ok or not

Comment: Can someone please tell if method has a class as arguments e.g.
void check(Booking) where booking is an argument of another class.
How I can use that in JUNIT5 Test and allocate a value to it ?

Comment: Why do you test if `booking` is an instance of class `Booking`? Wouldn't it make more sense to check if the room is in `State.READY` after `checkout`?

Comment: Can you please write a piece of code and show me how to do it ?

Comment: I have updated my question with full code. Please guide me where I am making mistake thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code snippet, it looks like you have two methods i.e. book the hotel and check-out the same.
The general concept of unit test to test the code written in that particular class. So, your end goal will be to test `book` and `checkout` method in the different test case.

You are getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` because your `bookings` attribute is `null` due to wrong use of `@Spy` annotation.

```
@Spy 
List <Booking> bookings = new ArrayList<>();
```

You should use `@Spy` as shown above and it will solve your null pointer exception:

You can refer below link to read how to use `@Spy` @ https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy